# Response from email

Tags: javascript, html, adonis.js, cloudmailin

I am using cloudmailin and receiving all the reply mails(If someone replies to the emails i send them), now when i do request.raw(), i get all my replies in string format like this:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "received": "xxx.google.com with SMTP id c1so1731393vsh.8        for <xxxx@cloudmailin.net>; Sun, 06 Jun 2021 20:19:02 -0700",
    "date": "Mon, 07 Jun 2021 08:48:53 +0530",
    "from": "ABC <xxx@gmail.com>",
    "to": "xxx@cloudmailin.net",
    "message_id": "<xxx@mail.gmail.com>",
    "in_reply_to": "<xxx@gmail.com>",
    "references": "<xxx@gmail.com>",
    "subject": "Re: Update On Your Ticket #66",
    "mime_version": "1.0",
    "content_type": "multipart/alternative; boundary=000000000000c465af05c4248031",
    "dkim_signature": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;        h=mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date:message-id:subject:to;        bh=bD3ONqLV7AId5UzdUHe8gDLobCQrtQFYsq2u/8iYIhk=;        b=CEHWz5AC3REury8SN4wyg8wxum9H0CmXqT3XJTOjdP0pa5YpCXHPUDMjjLgYf0upd6         rM7qOI7GGHmzNGATmjxu/iQhRD5VaVxOi/VBrExMwlbFzXz8Dg6PoILI2dDnn5oZuzWi         zwujwLEVm7VcY2hetWrJYlBfzL5FtSa5W7gZDH42EyqYTDyzLPhWYBPueCSjqfgbXfWH         Wb2roecATRV+W9GQZNF7oOKbvpW5ASjzys7a5Llo2xkVfqlvsJli5aIFlUoY1nozj/v7         D/0zkojKlmyDUGEqRxrcIU8JFPm8gl0Ctnx1GgjiZ2vkvWv9oUNpMZdQU3khTbO8WzSV         ss7Q==",
    "x_google_dkim_signature": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date         :message-id:subject:to; 
       bh=bD3ONqLV7AId5UzdUHe8gDLobCQrtQFYsq2u/8iYIhk=;        b=Zs0h+EM3gcygNli6sm5CpodTr1kziEkj+W5ceiKiaGo2XZVMOXq85IZBY5jaOUspmF         R15pIV36BDP1mI2y0GbRE+jcIq7I6MjIxpDusRrxMDnADYyS5jRNk2YfqJC+4ml2MLSz         LGX+4JugPBp4QJq1dDPAGrqP8hfrXNLXcDZx7rUck9LCgbP59nUvDNndYUcbF45xa+oV         RvCvYo7ue69ogrc+/DM1b2uzP+lU7oY68yFhpfEGctWGaj36vsOcgrSA+FM7bB0UChWI         HVhRwFIzq+tdKH+lJvqMbnxeCSqSL8p0TofGHEKfN4D+POaYVLW59wegz5i7K2Vdpq/l         Spog==",
    "x_gm_message_state": "AOAM533Hi5baxQtGjkRr4KU1AyKeRfihKQKBKyyQu6Si4uto+Fy8F1jB\tZamxinSc8qQ6vbsNhXqvOvuhBP5iFo23kcz2DEfqY28=",
    "x_google_smtp_source": "ABdhPJzSzz9bec+GYLzqjqOWnZ4BOEmm8Yt56FcCc0cr2D6Pag5pWL+Qq2Q7SBXzw+7gBxq1onhFX1KhlhE6yjxuyu4=",
    "x_received": "by 2002:a05:6102:dca:: with SMTP id e10mr2789248vst.47.1623035941773; Sun, 06 Jun 2021 20:19:01 -0700 (PDT)"
  },
  "envelope": {
    "to": "xxx@cloudmailin.net",
    "recipients": [
      "xxx@cloudmailin.net"
    ],
    "from": "xxx@gmail.com",
    "helo_domain": "xxx.google.com",
    "remote_ip": "abc.de.fg.ql",
    "tls": true,
    "tls_cipher": "TLSv1.3",
    "md5": "xxx",
    "spf": {
      "result": "neutral",
      "domain": "gmail.com"
    }
  },
  "plain": "Yes, what about you?\n\nOn Mon, Jun 7, 2021 at 8:48 AM <xxx@gmail.com> wrote:\n\n> xxx@gmail.com replied to your ticket\n>\n> Message: all cool?\n>\n",
  "html": "<div dir=\"ltr\">Yes, what about you?</div><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div dir=\"ltr\" class=\"gmail_attr\">On Mon, Jun 7, 2021 at 8:48 AM &lt;<a href=\"mailto:xxx@gmail.com\">xxx@gmail.com</a>&gt; wrote:<br></div><blockquote class=\"gmail_quote\" style=\"margin:0px 0px 0px 0.8ex;border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204);padding-left:1ex\"><a href=\"mailto:xxx@gmail.com\" 
target=\"_blank\">xxx@gmail.com</a> replied to your ticket <br><p>Message: all cool?</p>\r\n</blockquote></div>\r\n",
  "reply_plain": "Yes, what about you?",
  "attachments": [

  ]
}
```

how to get only the `html` part from this message? I cannot loop through the object as it is a string, from this entire data i want only the html part of the message.
**can you help me with this?**

Comment: Use JSON.parse() to parse the response string to a JSON object then access it via the html property

Comment: if i do JSON.parse(), it is getting converted to JSON, but i am not able to map through it, it says .map is not a function, is there any other alternative i can use for map?

Comment: You don't map through it, it's a JSON object you just do .html or ["html"] to get that property of the JSON Object

Comment: OH YEAH, your right. But how do i access the subject, it is inside headers?Can you help me with that too

Comment: Uhm yea, so you would just access it with .headers.subject

Comment: yes, sure, :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.parse() to parse the response string to a JSON object. From there, you can use standard property access to get the values you need.

Example:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(....);
const html = data.html;
const subject = data.headers.subject;
```